# Where is the (.app) project directory in iOS

Tags: ios, xcode5

I need to test my app with AppScanner for `private API`.

AppScanner said like following.

You can use App Scanner one of three ways:  drop a compiled simulator .app folder into the GUI to scan the app, type method signatures into the search text field, or integrate the command line version into your build phase as part of a script to automatically check code right after it is compiled by `Xcode`.

I don't know where to find `.app` folder that compiled simulator.

Where is it?

Comment: `Products` -> `YourApp.app`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.app` is in the  `Products` Folder in your `Xcode` project.

[image]

As its `Red` now So you need to Build on a `iOS` device then it will be `Black` then Right Click and choose `Show in Finder`(it will open a finder window with `.app` location).

Answer (score 1):

Here is path to iPhone Simulator path folder:

> ~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/[OS
>   version]/Applications/[appGUID]/

There you can find .app file.